# How can I fix my controller so that it doesn't return duplicate items?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I created a .Net 5 Entity Framework Core web app.  I let Visual Studio create the Models automatically from the database/dbcontext class.

The system works well, but I have this one controller that returns a list of breweries:

```
// GET: api/LocalBreweries
[HttpGet("LocalBreweries")]
public  List<Brewery> LocalBreweries()
{
    var breweries = _context.Brewery
        .Include(p => p.Market)
        .Include(p => p.Brewmaster)
        .Where(p => p.IsSeasonal == true)
        .ToList();
        
    foreach (var brewery in breweries)  
    {
        _ProcessData(brewery, brewery.Market, brewery.Brewmaster);
    }
        
    return breweries;
}
```

Based on the `.Where` clause, I should only be getting back 10 results.

In fact, when I set a breakpoint, I can see that `breweries` contains 10 items, which is correct.

However, when I navigate to the API controller endpoint in my browser, I get a huge list of breweries with tons of duplicates of the same breweries over and over.

I am not quite sure why this is happening, but I think it might have to do with how Entity Framework set up my Models.

When I comment out both of the `Include` statements above, the controller endpoint only returns the 10 results and no duplicates.

My question is, is there a way to fix my controller so that it doesn't return a huge list of duplicate breweries?

Thanks!

Here are my models for this controller:

```
public partial class Brewery
{
    public Brewery()
    {
        BreweryTrainees = new HashSet<BreweryTrainees>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public bool IsSeasonal { get; set; }
    public long BrewmasterId { get; set; }
    public long MarketId { get; set; }

    public virtual Brewmaster Brewmaster { get; set; }
    public virtual Market Market { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<BreweryTrainees> BreweryTrainees { get; set; }
}

public partial class Brewmaster
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Brewery> Brewery { get; set; }
}

public partial class Market
{
    public Market()
    {
        Brewery = new HashSet<Brewery>();
    }

    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Brewery> Brewery { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Always return DTO not Model classes, and you will never have such issues.

Comment: Anyway, try `AsNoTracking()`, it will prevent fixup navigation properties.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv is a DTO just a custom class composed of the properties I want to return?  In this case, would it be a class with my brewery info, brewmaster info and market info all in one class?

Comment: @SkyeBoniwell Yes, a DTO (= Data Transfer Object) only contains the data that you want to transmit

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv thanks, the `AsNoTracking()` worked.  Would you still make a DTO?

Comment: DTO always preferable. It is API interface. Database schema may change, sometimes cardinally in this case you will broke UI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's becouse of ReferenceLoop in your model you can return json instead of list and ignore ReferenceLoop in it like this:

```
return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(breweries, Formatting.Indented,new JsonSerializerSettings { ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore});
```

I hope be helpful for you.

Comment: Besides this fix, it's advised to add DTO classes so that you know what you are returning to the user. The last DTO child object should not contain a LIST and should in turn stop the reference loop.